Use Powershell to enable "Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer" checkbox in a network adapter?
I would like to have a Powershell script which enables the "Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer" checkbox, which is the bottom one shown in this image:

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to enable the checkbox:
$macAddress = "XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX"
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.MacAddress -eq $macAddress -and $_.Name -eq "Ethernet"}
Set-NetAdapterPowerManagement -Name $adapter.Name -WakeOnPattern Disabled -WakeOnMagicPacket Enabled

When I run this, it doesn't throw any errors, but the checkbox value doesn't change, so clearly I'm doing something wrong. I tested by printing the adapter name and I'm confident the first two lines are returning the correct adapter, so there is something wrong with the final line of code. What is the correct way to enable this in Powershell? This is Windows 10 version 21H2.

Within Advanced there should be a property that handes this function.  For your specific adapter what is the name of the property?

@Ramhound, is it one of these properties? I'm not exactly sure how to get to what you're referring to: https://pastebin.com/jwGGtnxJ
